# MassTransit not subscribing to AzureServiceBus Topic

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm currently trying to update application that was originally .NET Core 3.1 using MassTransit 6.3.2. It is now configured to use .NET 6.0 and MassTransit 7.3.0

Our application uses MassTransit to send messages via Azure Service Bus, publishing messages to Topics, which then have other Subscribers listening to those Topic.

Cut down, it was implemented like so:

```cs
// Program.cs
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
   config.AddConsumer<AppointmentBookedMessageConsumer>();
   config.AddBus(BusControlFactory.ConfigureAzureServiceBus);
});


// BusControlFactory.cs
public static class BusControlFactory
{
   public static IBusControl ConfigureAzureServiceBus(IRegistrationContext<IServiceProvider> context)
   {
      var config = context.Container.GetService<AppConfiguration>();
      var azureServiceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(busFactoryConfig =>
      {
         busFactoryConfig.Host("Endpoint=sb://REDACTED-queues.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=MyMessageQueuing;SharedAccessKey=MyKeyGoesHere");
         busFactoryConfig.Message<AppointmentBookedMessage>(m => m.SetEntityName("appointment-booked"));
         busFactoryConfig.SubscriptionEndpoint<AppointmentBookedMessage>(
            "my-subscriber-name",
            configurator =>
            {
               configurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
               configurator.Consumer<AppointmentBookedMessageConsumer>(context.Container);
            });
         return azureServiceBus;
      }
   }
}
```

It has now been changed and upgraded to the latest MassTransit and is implemented like:

```cs
// Program.cs
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
   config.AddConsumer<AppointmentBookedMessageConsumer, AppointmentBookedMessageConsumerDefinition>();
   config.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => 
   {
      cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://REDACTED-queues.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=MyMessageQueuing;SharedAccessKey=MyKeyGoesHere");
      cfg.Message<AppointmentBookedMessage>(m => m.SetEntityName("appointment-booked"));

      cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});


// AppointmentBookedMessageConsumerDefinition.cs
public class AppointmentBookedMessageConsumerDefinition: ConsumerDefinition<AppointmentBookedMessageConsumer>
{
   public AppointmentBookedMessageConsumerDefinition()
   {
      EndpointName = "testharness.subscriber";
   }

   protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<AppointmentBookedMessageConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
   {
      endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
   }
}
```

The *issue* if it can be considered one, is that I can't bind to a subscription that already exists.

In the example above, you can see that the `EndpointName` is set as "testharness.subscriber". There was already a subscription to the Topic "appointment-booked" from prior to me upgrading. However, when the application runs, it does not error, but it receives no messages.

If I change the `EndpointName` to "testharness.subscriber2". Another subscriber appears in the Azure Service Bus topic (via the Azure Portal) and I start receiving messages. I can see no difference in the names (other than the change that I placed, in this case: the "2" suffix).

Am I missing something here? Is there something else I need to do to get these to bind? Is my configuration wrong? Was it wrong? While I'm sure I can get around this by managing the release more closely and removing unneeded queues once they're using new ones - it feels like the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Azure Service Bus, `ForwardTo` on a subscription can be a bit opaque.

While the subscription may indeed visually indicate that it is forwarding to the correctly *named* queue, it *might* be that the queue was deleted and recreated at some point without deleting the subscription. This results in a subscription that will build up messages, as it is unable to forward them to a queue that no longer exists.

Why? Internally, a subscription maintains the `ForwardTo` as an *object id*, which after the queue is deleted points to an object that doesn't exist – resulting in messages building up in the subscription.

If you have messages in the subscription, you may need to go into the portal and *update* that subscription to point to the new queue (even though it has the same name), at which point the messages *should* flow through to the queue.

If there aren't any messages in the subscription (or if they aren't important), you can just delete the subscription and it will be recreated by MassTransit when you restart the bus.

Comment: That makes sense. So it's not that anything is specifically done wrong - it's just that MassTransit can't bind to the queue it used to bind to before. Therefore, the focus becomes about ensure that we don't lose messages, etc. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yeah, it's more that it "thinks" it's bound to the queue properly (the subscription _shows_ the right name), but the underlying object is referencing a queue that no longer exists.